# Why was this question closed as Too Localized?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, too-localized

On [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668313/how-to-put-multiple-style-attributes-in-jquery/16668356#16668356) question, OP asks how to add multiple attributes inside a `.css()` jquery function. The answer of course is by passing an object of the attributes, however, I'm struggling to see how this is localized?

> **How to put multiple style attributes in jquery [closed]**
>
> ```
> `$('#header').css('left', 200 - $this.scrollLeft());`
> ```
>
> I need to put multiple style attributes in the above line. The start and end part needs to be intact.
>
> Please help. Thanks in advance.

Admittedly it is something that could easily have been found in a few seconds by googling, but the question itself isn't localized to the OP.

Comment: what do you recommend as a closing reason for "general reference" questions? None of them really fit (except maybe Duplicate), and you don't want to encourage lazy askers.

Comment: Because democracy. Or instead of a system explanation are you actually asking us to interpret the thoughts and reasoning of the closers on their behalf? -1 just because the formulation of this question. If your intent is to have it reopened then outright ask for aid in that after offering your own rationale, if you're just curious then these principles (rather, the guidelines of users with free-will, such as it is) have been thoroughly explained in many a previous question/answer sets.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment I was asking whether it was correct to close it as Too Localized, rather than why each individual voter voted so. Jan, I would have thought it was maybe a "duplicate" or not closed at all - a  simple google is arguably the fix for a lot of issues that don't get closed as too localized

Comment: But what does it ultimately matter? Is there a point?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment Purely for my own, and possibly others in the future, understanding. And maybe spark a discussion as to whether another close-question option should be created to prevent misuse of Too Localized

Comment: @Andy Oh there'll be murder on just for mentioning that last bit. Seriously, though, then that falls into the second part of my first comment: lots of exchanges of ideas on this, and if conventions, reasonable usage and potential for the occasional inexplicable closing, isn't able to be gleaned from current content then I fear it never will be.

Comment: I voted to close it as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447197/how-to-define-multiple-css-attributes-in-jquery - we can probably all agree on that one. `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not too localized.

It is, however, [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447197/how-to-define-multiple-css-attributes-in-jquery). I've closed it as such.

Thanks for bringing this up. In the future this is a case where you can vote to re-open, and if there's no traction, bring it to our attention through a moderator flag.

Since we have a review queue, these requests should go through that queue whenever possible.